# System.NullReferenceException when trying to read config file from a unit test project

Tags: c#

Am doing a unit test, testing my connection string. This is the code I have on my test method:

```
 [TestMethod()]
    public void connectionStringTest()
    {
        //string expected = null; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        string actual;

        string expected = " User Id=ownitsbio;Password=ownitsbio;Data Source=preprod";
        actual = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ownitsbio"].ConnectionString;

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
        //Assert.Inconclusive(expected);

    }
```

I get this error `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`. What could be the problem?? Please help!

Comment: This is possibly *the* most basic problem to debug, using the debugger to check exactly what part of the `X.Y.Z` line evaluates to `null`.

Comment: @jon I agree, but to his defense, it is not always obvious to a novice tester that the config-file which will be read is not that from the system under test, but rather the one under the Test-project. ;)  (Side-note; this is, speaking, not a "unit test", but rather an integration test, as it depends on something outside the pure logic of a single unit of code. Take care to keep the two types of tests separate, ideally in two separate projects).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an App.config to your test project, and have the connection string there.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that doesn't exist connection string `ownitsbio` on your test config file.

If you don't have any, create one and add this connection string.

Answer (score 1):

You test framework needs the setting in its configuration file (web.config or app.config). The test framework usually does not use the configuration file that is part of your program. Therefore the ownitsbio connection string does not exist and you are getting the null reference exception when trying to read the `ConnectionString` property.